# Extracting an entire Jenkins stage to a shared library?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to take an entire `stage('foo') {...}` definition and extract it into a shared library within Jenkins? The docs are very clear on how to pull an individual step out, but I can't find any way to take an entire stage, parameterize it, and re-use it globally. I thought perhaps just `return stage...` would work, but it errors out as an invalid return value.

Comment: I'm also thinking about this. However script {} is only allowed inside steps {} so how would you inject it

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It depends if you use **scripted** or **declarative** pipeline.

**Scripted pipeline** is more flexible and it allows you e.g. create stages based on some conditions (each pipeline run can have a different number and kind of stages). In this kind of pipeline you can extract a full stage to the shared library class and call it from inside the `node {}` block. Consider following example:

```groovy
// src/ScriptedFooStage.groovy
class ScriptedFooStage {
    private final Script script

    ScriptedFooStage(Script script) {
        this.script = script
    }

    // You can pass as many parameters as needed
    void execute(String name, boolean param1) {
        script.stage(name) {
            script.echo "Triggering ${name} stage..."
            script.sh "echo 'Execute your desired bash command here'"

            if (param1) {
                script.sh "echo 'Executing conditional command, because param1 == true'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the *Jenkinsfile* may look like this:

```groovy
node {
    new ScriptedFooStage(this).execute('Foo', true)
}
```

As you can see the whole stage was encapsulated in the `ScriptedFooStage.execute()` method. Its name is also taken from the parameter `name` - scripted pipeline allows you doing such thing.

---

**Declarative pipeline** on the other hand is more strict and opinionated. It's fixed if it comes to the number of stages and their names (you can't model dynamically what stages are present per build and what are their names). You can still take advantage of shared library classes, but you are limited to execute them inside `script {}` block inside `stage('Name') { steps {} }` block. It means that you can't extract the whole stage to the separate class, but only some part that gets executed at the steps level. Consider following example:

```groovy
// src/DeclarativeFooStage.groovy
class DeclarativeFooStage {
    private final Script script

    DeclarativeFooStage(Script script) {
        this.script = script
    }

    // You can pass as many parameters as needed
    void execute(String name, boolean param1) {
        script.echo "Triggering script with name == ${name}"
        script.sh "echo 'Execute your desired bash command here'"

        if (param1) {
            script.sh "echo 'Executing conditional command, because param1 == true'"
        }
    }
}
```

And the *Jenkinsfile* may look like this:

```groovy
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Foo') {
            steps {
                script {
                    new DeclarativeFooStage(this).execute('something', false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we would try execute `new DeclarativeFooStage(this).execute('something', false)` outside `script {}` block in the declarative pipeline we would get compilation errors.

#### Conclusion

The choice between scripted or declarative pipeline depends on specific use case. If you want to get the best flexibility when it comes to modeling your pipeline business logic, scripted pipeline might be the good choice. However, it comes with some price. For instance, scripted pipeline does not support restarting pipeline build from specific stage - this is supported only by declarative pipeline. (Imagine you have 10 stages in the pipeline and stage 7 failed because of some silly mistake and you would like to restart the build from 7th stage - in scripted pipeline you would have to re-run from the very beginning, while declarative pipeline can restart from 7th stage by remembering the results from all 6 previous stages).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, it helped me allot. Nevertheless, can you please elaborate a little about what exactly happens when you pass the `this` argument to ctor of the `DeclarativeFooStage` class (is it this type of object:https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html). I mean, in run time, what is it exactly? I'm very new to Groovy, Java and Jenkins, so I hope this is not an entirely naïve question...Thank you in advance.

Comment: CpsScript object is passed.

More info: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.html

It allows you to use plugins inside your custom class (like sh, or git) https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/

Answer (score 2):

To complete Szymon Stepniak answer I will leave here note that in declarative pipeline you may also share whole pipeline:

```
// vars/myDeliveryPipeline.groovy
def call(Map pipelineParams) {

    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('build') {
                ...
            }

            stage ('test') {
                ...
            }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it

```
// Jenkinsfile
myDeliveryPipeline(foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR')
```

But as far as remember you may call only one pipeline in a Jenkins file which make it not very customizable.

**Source**

https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/