# Jenkins: Is it possible to import pipeline stages from other files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a usecase, where I have multiple pipelines but each running same piece of code for each stage, only difference being some will run all stages, some will run few.
If I create separate **Jenkinsfile** having same code for stages, and if someday I change a config, i will have to change everywhere.
So is it possible to create `stage` in a separate file as a shared-library, and then just import them in the pipeline-specific Jenkinsfile?
For example if I have a pipeline-1 that run all *stages A,B, and C*.
Pipeline-2 runs only *stage B*.
and pipeline runs *stage A and C*.
Can i create 3 separate files:
**A.groovy**

```
stage('A') {
    steps {
        //something
    }
}
```

**B.groovy**

```
stage('B') {
    steps {
        //something
    }
}
```

**C.groovy**

```
stage('C') {
    steps {
        //something
    }
}
```

So in Pipeline-1 Jenkinsfile I can use:

```
pipeline {
    agent any      
    stages {
        import A
        A.call()
        import B
        B.call()
        import C
        C.call()
    }
}
```

And so on.
I know syntactically above is not correct, its just to explain what needs to be done.

Comment: Checkout the [load](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) step, which an be used to Evaluate a Groovy source file into the Pipeline script

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to extract the entire stage into a separate file and use it from a shared library. It is possible to extract an entire stage into a shared library, but it becomes very complicated with declarative pipelines. Scripted pipelines on the other hand allow you to do this in a much simple manner. There is a well detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204143/3730626) which goes into detail about how you can accomplish what you want using both types of pipelines. In the case of scripted pipelines, the solution is to create a class with the stage you want in it, then reference the stage via the class like so:

```
node {
    new ScriptedStage(this).execute('Foo', true)
}
```

Refer to the previously mentioned answer to get more information.